# FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()) method not worked

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm use Facebook SDK 4.5.1 (import facebook package) `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext())` not worked...

this is error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.FacebookSdk
```

code is

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LanguageUtils.LanguageSettings(this);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  }
```

My project is older (min Android sdk is 10). I'm use new version sdk (Facebook SDK 4.7.0)  it worked true, But it supported (Android sdk 14 ->)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```